# How to make a Scrollable Layout and Zoomable Layout in an Android App?

Tags: android

I am making an Android App and i need one of my Layouts to have Zoom control and have it be Scrollable Vertical, but i don't know how to successfully do this?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'layouts to have Zoom control'.

Answer (score -1):

[use this jar in your application](http://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/downloads/list)

```
private ZoomView zoomView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoomable);

View v = ((LayoutInflater)   getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.zoomableview, null, false);
v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
zoomView.addView(v);

main_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container);
main_container.addView(zoomView);            }
```