# How to make zoom in / out scrollview in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll, scrollview, pinchzoom

In my android application I need to create activities zoom able.nut in my application couple of activities start with scrollview and this code does not recognize scrollview. How can I make pinch zoom for scrollable activity? This is one of my layout.

also tried also ScaleGestureDetector and 
[How to make zoomable scrollview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615697/how-to-make-zoomable-scrollview)

**want to do zoom in/out scrollview. thanx your help will be appriciated**

thanks in advance

**This Is My Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fillViewport="false">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wd_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Start Circle -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row_circl1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle_layout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_engin_circle1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row_name_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle_name_layout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_name_circle1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_engin_circle2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle_name_layout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_name_circle2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/circle_layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="172dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="172dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/circle_layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="172dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLaysdfout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="172dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/circle_laysdfout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="172dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dsf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="172dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- End Circle -->

    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

**this is my activity**

**zoom in out working perfect but i cant move left to right or vise-versa  like in our photo gallary image view**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
        horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.vertical); 

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());    

        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                float scale = 1 - detector.getScaleFactor();

                float prevScale = mScale;
                mScale += scale;

                if (mScale < 0.1f) // Minimum scale condition:
                    mScale = 0.1f;

                if (mScale > 10f) // Maximum scale condition:
                    mScale = 10f;
                ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f / prevScale, 1f / mScale, 1f / prevScale, 1f / mScale, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                scaleAnimation.setDuration(0);
                scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                scrollView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                horizontalScrollView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

 override dispatchTouchEvent()
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }  


        private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
            // event when double tap occurs
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                // double tap fired.
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: hello ,did you find the solution?

Comment: no still not find proper solution if i will, i will share @isha

Comment: Thanks @mehul for reply..i  need  same solution

Comment: @isha hey found this solution may help you http://eminosoft.blogspot.in/2013/06/zooming-for-layout-in-android.html

Comment: Thanks @mehul.. i will check it out

Answer (score 0):

In Dispatch touch event use ActionType and separate each MotionEventActions and write logics for each and every type in which the certain action needs to be performed.

[How to make a Scrollable Layout and Zoomable Layout in an Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772565/how-to-make-a-scrollable-layout-and-zoomable-layout-in-an-android-app)

This may help you pretty much.